# How to keep square brackets in single array using Logic Apps?

Tags: arrays, azure-logic-apps, xml-to-json

I am parsing an XML document to JSON, and eventhough I have the type array declared in the json schema, if there is just one element in the array it gets transformed into an objet like this.

"ListOfCodes":{"Codes":{{"Code":"111"}}}

but I need this:
"ListOfCodes":{"Codes":[{"Code":"111"}]}

I have several arrays in the document and I only get the sqare brackets when there is a multiple array.
and adding the properties manually is not an option.
Anyone know what can i modify to fix this in the logic app?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your xml ? I will test with it to find if there is a solution.

Comment: Added an XML Example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a good solution for us to implement this requirement in logic app. Here is another [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/03fe9c57-b7a8-41aa-ade4-652b6b5eafc3/single-element-xml-to-json-array?forum=azurelogicapps) which is  similar to your problem. To implement the requirement, we can just:

**1.** Use the "Compose" action to generate the object by hand (manually put all the properties and arrays where they need, potentially using the @array() action.

**2.** Call an Azure Function or some external code that can more specifically craft a valid JSON.

I also try to test it in some other way, such as use `json:Array="true"` and use `<?xml-multiple?>` but they all fail in logic app. So I think the only above two solutions(mentioned in that post) can be used. Neither approach is good, though.

Comment: Thank you, i resolved the issue by transforming XML with an XSLT File and convert the XML to Text to my desired json output.